# MPI and OpenMP on Apple Silicon M1 Pro

Tags: c++, macos, clang, apple-m1, apple-silicon

So, someone has to initiate such a question regarding apple silicon. Long story short, I need to compile and run a `C++` code that runs **hybrid with both MPI and OpenMP on a MBP M1 pro** (which uses arm-based architecture). The code runs perfectly fine on a typical Intel x86 architecture. Also, for completion sake, the Mac OS is Monterey. Additionally, I do not compile/run via an IDE (e.g. XCode), I do so via a Makefile, directly from the terminal.

I haven't found a clear answer to such a question. I tried setting things up myself, but this is way above my comfort zone. Moreover, I trust answering such a question would help future developers that are using these Macs for work :)

So far, I understood that the installed Clang compiler that comes with Xcode does not support OpenMP (`-fopenmp`) or recognizes MPI (`mpirun`). So, I installed "brew" and the "`llvm`" version which should support the multi-threading instructions via OpenMP. As for the MPI library, I installed the "`libomp`" library through "`brew`". These all should run natively on Apple Silicon.

However, now the environment is all over the place, since the system has 2 Clang compilers:

- one preinstalled with Xcode (the default)
- one installed via brew, situated in: `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm`

I do not know how to proceed. The simple solution might be to change the path of the compiler to that in the `/opt/homebrew/` directory, however I suspect that might mess a lot of things in the system.

I would (and many others) be very thankful if you could help, in case someone has prior experience with something like this before.

Answer (score 2):

To use Homebrew's Clang you will need set up your PATH and compiler flags accordingly.

Actually, Homebrew gives you the respective advice and hints already once you install llvm (or try `brew info llvm`):

```
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
```

You will need to forward those flags into your build setup, i.e., if you have build files from CMake/Make/whatsoever you will need to make sure that the respective flags are used or forwarded.